# Up Button not working if the activity extends AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-fragmentactivity, up-button

I launched **Activity B** via deep link and I'm expecting **Activity A** to be launched on Up Button click.

Here's my manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activity.B"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_search"
    android:parentActivityName=".ui.activity.A" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".ui.activity.A"/>
        ...
        <!-- deep link -->
        ...     
</activity>
```

B Activity code is here.

```
public class B extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Toolbar vToolbar = ((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        setSupportActionBar(vToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

You can copy/past this code and it works if **Activity B**  extends [FragmentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html). But I need this to be working with [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're opening your `Activity` from another application. So there is no other `Activity` available in the stack. Thus you should not get the parent `Activity` to come up in the front when you press the up button. If the target parent activity is in the task's back stack, it is brought forward.  From the developers [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html).

> However, using `navigateUpFromSameTask()` is suitable only when your
>   app is the owner of the current task (that is, the user began this
>   task from your app). If that's not true and your activity was started
>   in a task that belongs to a different app, then navigating Up should
>   create a new task that belongs to your app, which requires that you
>   create a new back stack.

So in your case you need to do something like this stated in the documentation.

> If your activity provides any intent filters that allow other apps to
>   start the activity, you should implement the `onOptionsItemSelected()`
>   callback such that if the user presses the Up button after entering
>   your activity from another app's task, your app starts a new task with
>   the appropriate back stack before navigating up.
>
> You can do so by first calling `shouldUpRecreateTask()` to check
>   whether the current activity instance exists in a different app's
>   task. If it returns true, then build a new task with
>   `TaskStackBuilder`. Otherwise, you can use the
>   `navigateUpFromSameTask()` method as shown above.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
        if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
            // This activity is NOT part of this app's task, so create a new task
            // when navigating up, with a synthesized back stack.
            TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                    // Add all of this activity's parents to the back stack
                    .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                    // Navigate up to the closest parent
                    .startActivities();
        } else {
            // This activity is part of this app's task, so simply
            // navigate up to the logical parent activity.
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: shouldUpRecreateTask() is returning false, should it be returning true on a deep link ? that's why only the last line NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent); is executed